# How to updating dict items inside a list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this list of dicts that I'm maintaining as a master list:

```
orig_list = [
   { 'cpu': '4', 'mem': '4', 'name': 'server1', 'drives': '4', 'nics': '1' }
   { 'cpu': '1', 'mem': '2', 'name': 'server2', 'drives': '2', 'nics': '2' }
   { 'cpu': '2', 'mem': '8', 'name': 'server3', 'drives': '1', 'nics': '1' }
   ]
```

However, I need to perform actions on things inside this list of dicts, like:

```
def modifyVM(local_list)
    local_temp_list = []
    for item in local_list :
        '''
        Tons of VM processy things happen here.
        '''
        item['cpu'] = 4
        item['notes'] = 'updated cpu'
    local_temp_list.append(item)
    return local_temp_list

temp_list []
for item in orig_list :
    if item['cpu'] < 4
        temp_list.append(item)

result_list = modifyVM(temp_list)
```

At this point, result_list contains:

```
result_list = [
    { 'cpu': '4', 'mem': '2', 'name': 'server2', 'drives': '2', 'nics': '2' }
    { 'cpu': '4', 'mem': '8', 'name': 'server3', 'drives': '1', 'nics': '1' }
    ]
```

So my questions are:

1) What is the most efficient way to update `orig_list` with the results of `result_list`?  I'm hoping to end up with:

```
orig_list = [
    { 'cpu': '4', 'mem': '4', 'name': 'server1', 'drives': '4', 'nics': '1' }
    { 'cpu': '4', 'mem': '2', 'name': 'server2', 'drives': '2', 'nics': '2' 'notes': 'updated cpu' }
    { 'cpu': '4', 'mem': '8', 'name': 'server3', 'drives': '1', 'nics': '1' 'notes': 'updated cpu' }
    ]
```

2) Is there a way to update `orig_list` without ever creating secondary lists?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't you just want `orig_list.extend(modifyVM(temp_list))`?

Comment: It would be simpler if `orig_list` were instead a dictionary with server name keys.

Comment: Also, you can use `filter()` to `result_list = list(filter(lambda item: item['cpu'] < 4, orig_list))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collections store references to the objects.

So the code you posted is already modifying the items in "orig_list" as well, cause all the lists are storing references to the same original dictionaries.

As for the second part of your question, you don't need to create a new list. You can modify the objects directly, and next time you iterate the list you'll see the updated values.

Like for example:

```
orig_list = [
   { 'cpu': 4, 'mem': '4', 'name': 'server1', 'drives': '4', 'nics': '1' },
   { 'cpu': 1, 'mem': '2', 'name': 'server2', 'drives': '2', 'nics': '2' },
   { 'cpu': 2, 'mem': '8', 'name': 'server3', 'drives': '1', 'nics': '1' }
   ]

print orig_list

for item in orig_list :
    if item['cpu'] < 4:
        item['cpu'] = 4

print orig_list
```

Output of first print:

```
[{'mem': '4', 'nics': '1', 'drives': '4', 'cpu': 4, 'name': 'server1'},
 {'mem': '2', 'nics': '2', 'drives': '2', 'cpu': 1, 'name': 'server2'},
 {'mem': '8', 'nics': '1', 'drives': '1', 'cpu': 2, 'name': 'server3'}]
```

And second print:

```
[{'mem': '4', 'nics': '1', 'drives': '4', 'cpu': 4, 'name': 'server1'},
 {'mem': '2', 'nics': '2', 'drives': '2', 'cpu': 4, 'name': 'server2'},
 {'mem': '8', 'nics': '1', 'drives': '1', 'cpu': 4, 'name': 'server3'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to create a separate list, just use list comprehension.

Just iterate through the list and check if value of `cpu` key is less than 4. If value is less than 4, then update value the `cpu` key to 4 and add an extra key `notes` having value as `'updated_cpu'`. Value of `orig_list` after iteration finishes is the desired result.

```
>>> orig_list = [{'cpu': 4, 'drives': '4', 'mem': '4', 'name': 'server1', 'nics': '1'},
 {'cpu': 1, 'drives': '2', 'mem': '2', 'name': 'server2', 'nics': '2'},
 {'cpu': 2, 'drives': '1', 'mem': '8', 'name': 'server3', 'nics': '1'}]

>>> for item in orig_list:
        if item['cpu']<4:
            item['cpu']=4
            item['notes'] = 'updated cpu'

>>> orig_list
[{'cpu': 4, 'drives': '4', 'mem': '4', 'name': 'server1', 'nics': '1'},
 {'cpu': 4, 'drives': '2', 'mem': '2', 'name': 'server2', 'nics': '2', 'notes': 'updated cpu'},
 {'cpu': 4, 'drives': '1', 'mem': '8', 'name': 'server3', 'nics': '1', 'notes': 'updated cpu'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the input!  I flagged eugenioy's post as the answer because he posted first.  Both the answer from him and from Rahul Gupta are very efficient ways to update a list of dictionaries.

However, I kept trying other ways because these answers, as efficient as they are, still do one other thing I've always been told is taboo: modifying the list you're iterating over.

Keep in mind, that I'm still learning Python.  So if some of my "revelations" here are mundain, they are new and "wow" to me.  To that effect, I'm adding the answer that I actually ended up implementing.

Here's the finished code:

```
def modifyVM(local_list, l_orig_list)
    for item in local_list[:] :
    l_orig_list.remove(item)
        '''
        Tons of VM processy things happen here.
        '''
        item['cpu'] = 4
        item['notes'] = 'updated cpu'
    l_orig_list.append(item)

temp_list []
for item in orig_list[:] :
    if item['cpu'] < 4
        temp_list.append(item)

modifyVM(temp_list, orig_list)
```

I change this line:

```
def modifyVM(local_list)
```

To this line:

```
def modifyVM(local_list, l_orig_list)
```

In this way, I'm passing in both the list I want to use as well as the list I want to update.

Next I changed:

```
for item in local_list :
```

To this line:

```
for item in local_list[:] :
```

This causes "item" to iterate through a slice (copy) of "local_list" that contains everything.

I also added:

```
l_orig_list.remove(item)
```

And:

```
l_orig_list.append(item)
```

This solved several problems for me.

1)  This avoids the potential of modifying any list that's being iterated through.

2)  This allows "orig_list" to be updated as processes are happening, which cuts down on the "secondary lists" that are created and maintained.

3)  The "orig_list" that's passed into the function and "l_orig_list" are linked variables until a hard assignment (i.e. l_orig_list = 'anything') is made.  (Again, thank you to everyone that answered!  This was some great "secret sauce" learning for me, and y'all pointed it out.)  So, avoiding the "=", I'm able to update "l_orig_list" and have "orig_list" updated as well.

4)  This also allows the movement of items from one list to another if needed (i.e. list items that generate errors can be removed from "orig_list" and placed in any other list, like "bad_list" for example.

In closing, I'd like to give recognition to Steven Rumbalski.  When I read your comment, I was like, "Of course!!!"  However, I spent 2 days on it before realizing that dictionaries cannot be sorted.  I had to narrow down the technical problem I was facing to ask a question here.  Sorting was an unstated requirement for other parts of the script.  So GREAT suggestion, and I'll probably use that for another script.